# What's the proper lib variable for a makefile?

Tags: makefile

Running into trouble with libraries in makefiles again. Every time I try to get back into C make gives me a pain with libs.

`make -pf /dev/null` says the correct vars should be `LDLIBS` and `LOADLIBES` but the following doesn't alter the run command at all:

```
LOADLIBES=testing
LDFLAGS=testing
LDLIBS=testing
```

Needless to say this gives me errors because the `-L` flags don't end up in the command. Anyone know what's going on?

Full makefile below (Derivitave of Z Shaw's makefile)

```
OPTLIBS=$(xml2-config --libs)
OPTFLAGS=$(xml2-config --cflags)

STD=c99
CFLAGS=-std=$(STD) -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LDLIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)
PREFIX?=/usr/local



SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))

TARGET=build/lib.a
SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))

# The Target Build
all: cls $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET) tests

dev: CFLAGS=-std=$(STD) -g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@

$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

build:
    @mkdir -p build
    @mkdir -p bin

# The Unit Tests
$(TESTS): $(TARGET)

.PHONY: tests
tests: LDLIBS += $(TARGET)
tests: $(TESTS)
    sh ./tests/runtests.sh

valgrind:
    VALGRIND="valgrind --log-file=/tmp/valgrind-%p.log" $(MAKE)

# The Cleaner
clean: cls
    rm -rf build $(OBJECTS) $(TESTS)
    rm -f tests/tests.log
    find . -name "*.gc*" -exec rm {} \;
    rm -rf `find . -name "*.dSYM" -print`

# The Install
install: all
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/

# The Checker
BADFUNCS='[^_.>a-zA-Z0-9](str(n?cpy|n?cat|xfrm|n?dup|str|pbrk|tok|_)|stpn?cpy|a?sn?printf|byte_)'
check:
    @echo Files with potentially dangerous functions.
    @egrep $(BADFUNCS) $(SOURCES) || true

# Clear screen for unspammy terminals
cls:
ifdef TERM
    clear
endif
```

Comment: Note that `wildcard` only supports standard globbing, so `src/**/*.c` doesn't do what you expect.  Those variables _do_ work, for anything built using the default rules.  Please show us the link line where the libraries are missing and which part of the makefile you think is causing that target to be built.

Comment: It's using the default. That's why I'm so annoyed at it not working for no apparent reason.

Comment: I'm telling you that it's NOT using the default rules.  We can go back and forth with "yes it is" / "no it isn't" forever.  The only way to get out of this is for you to show us the make command you invoke and the output command line that make prints out which does not contain the values you are looking for, as I requested above.  Without this information we cannot help you.  With this information we can probably explain what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using `LDFLAGS`, etc in your link command. Make that something along the lines of:

```
$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: Nope - no change, "testing" is nowhere in the command. It's likely something on my system changed without my noticing that messed it up because this exact file was working fine a few months ago.

Comment: As said in the question, I stick `LOADLIBES=testing
LDFLAGS=testing
LDLIBS=testing` in the file and "testing" doesn't show up anywhere

Answer (score 0):

It tells the linker to link the dl library, which is located at /usr/lib/libdl.so. -l is the switch to add a library, dl is the name of it (without the lib prefix or .so extension).

This library includes functions for dynamically loading shared libraries.